# AsyncTask for loading image not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have simple code of an Asynctask which is to set and image to imageview after loading from Database. i Call this class in onCreateView of my fragment but image isn't in imageview.
Note - That table has only one row so i think nothing's wrong with the query.

```
         protected class setpro extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Set profile
        DataBaseOperations hell = new DataBaseOperations(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = hell.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic};
        Cursor cur = db.query(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        byte[] b = null;
        Bitmap bp = null;
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            b = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic));
        }
        if (b.length > 0) {
            bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
            cur.close();
            db.close();
            hell.close();
        }
            return bp;
    }
     @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if(result != null){
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.pro);
        iv.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

and here is my calling code.

```
      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    Button Setprofile = (Button) mview.findViewById(R.id.setprofile);
    // set profile pic
    new setpro().execute("whatever");
  }
```

Comment: is `Bitmap result` non-null? Add logcat statement there to tell you what is being passed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir,
you have get the bitmap from table but not binding it into image view so please add this code to your Asynctask

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {

iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: Lol i forgot to add it. Enjoy 10 reps :D

Comment: I don't know it wasn't working before now its working didn't change a single word. lol

Answer (score 0):

where is your `onPostExecute(Bitmap b){ }` method for class `setpro` ?

AsyncTask makes use of that to return results/ interact with UI thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html